# Openshift Enterprise 3.11 installation problem when deploy_cluster.yml

Tags: openshift

I tried to install Openshift 3.11 Enterprise version in RHEL 7.6. prerequisites.yml is success. When I try to start with deploy_cluster.yml

$ ansible-playbook -i playbooks/deploy_cluster.yml ansible-playbook execution failed with error stating "wait for control plane pods to appear"

Trying to

login to oc login -u sysadmin:admin

it says "unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout" –

when I do docker images I can see openshift images listing. when I do docker ps I do not see any run time container.

Not sure how to resolve this TLS handshake error. Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: How many resources does your master have? I've seen similar issues when there were too few CPUs/memory.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

I have 4 CPU i.e 8 cores and 16GB of memory allocated for master and 2 cores and 10GB for node. 
Got 2TB storage and docker_storage is 25GB on master and node. Named DNS is running on different server in same subnet. 
Both master and node is targeted to DNS server ip address in resolv.conf file. 

Not sure what is going wrong behind the screen.

Comment: Are there any containers in stopped state? If so, what is the log output of these containers? As stated on the following github issue, this problem can be caused by multiple things: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/10671#issuecomment-438378056

Comment: yes you are right. when I try for kubectl get pods it says cannot connect.
upon checking docker log for api container it says " context deadline exceeded " 

Not sure what needs to be done.
Upon restarting etcd service, api pod is getting exited automatically with " context deadline exceeded"